# GNUPlot: Animating a plane defined by three points

Tags: gnuplot

So I need to plot **planes** (as in, they HAVE to be FLAT) defined by three points which all come from my equation. I can redefine the code such that there is a space between the three points. I choose not to. I just added the comments for clarity of where the points are divided. They're not really there.

```
# surface 1
   1.000          0.000          0.000
 -46.777         -0.702         -1.692
   0.000          3.000          5.500
# surface 2
   0.998          0.030          0.055
 -46.451         -2.099         -5.068
  -0.468          2.993          5.483
# surface 3
   0.991          0.060          0.110
 -45.804         -3.471         -8.400
  -0.932          2.972          5.432
# surface 4
   0.979          0.089          0.164
 -44.842         -4.803        -11.659
  -1.390          2.937          5.348
# surface 5
   0.963          0.119          0.217
 -43.574         -6.079        -14.816
  -1.839          2.889          5.232
#... and so on
```

now I can plot just ONE surface using this code

```
set dgrid3d 10,10
set style data lines
set pm3d 
i=0
splot '5surf' every ::i::(i+2) pal
```

but when I plug it in a do loop

```
n =         1000
unset key

set terminal gif size 800,600 crop
outtmpl = 'pic/output%07d.gif'

set dgrid3d 10,10
set style data lines
set pm3d 

do for [i=0:n:3] {
set output sprintf(outtmpl, i)
splot '5surf' every ::i::(i+2) pal
print i
}
set output
```

I got curved surfaces with this, which is plain wrong. (pun intended)

The surface, according to my analysis, has to look a bit like it's rotating.

---

EDIT: I threw the dgrid3d out the window. Filledcurves didn't work. I was able to make a square with these points

```
1 1 4.8
-1 1 5.6
-1 -1 2.4
1 -1 1.6
1 1 4.8
```

using polygon, but I can't make it read from file.

---

last edit: If anyone stumbling across this is curious as to how I found the four points using the original set of three points, it was a matter of finding the equation of the plane containing the three points and plugging in (\pm 1, \pm 1, z) in there. Solve for z and consider all four cases. a basic calc problem, really

Comment: `dgrid3d` doesn't work properly for your application. You should probably calculate the four points which should delimit the plane you want to plot.

Comment: Okay, I have the equation for that, too. I tried it with four points, but all I got was a box. Now I need to fill it with some solid color for visibility, and when I try pm3d, it says there's not enough information for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the points for the square you must also insert an empty line to make `pm3d` work properly:

`surface.dat`:

```
-1 -1 2.4
-1 1 5.6

1 -1 1.6
1 1 4.8
```

Not, that the y-values are always in the same order `-1, 1` for both blocks. Plot this with

```
set pm3d
splot 'surface.dat'
```

[image]

If you want to put several surfaces from one file you can now separate two surfaces with *two* empty lines, which you can then access with `index`:

`surfaces.dat`:

```
-1 -1 2.4
-1 1 5.6

1 -1 1.6
1 1 4.8


-1 -1 1.4
-1 1 4.6

1 -1 0.6
1 1 3.8
```

You can use `stats` to count the number of blocks:

```
stats 'surfaces.dat' nooutput
set pm3d
do for [i=0:STATS_blocks - 1] {
    splot 'surfaces.dat' index i
}
```

Comment: is there a way to set the color for all the iterations? i got the do loop to work, but once the "slope" changes enough, the color changes

Comment: If you want a single color for all planes you should define a palette having only this color: `set palette defined (0 '#bb0000', 1 '#bb0000'); unset colorbox`.